# The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type FacebookFragment

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments, android-webview

I have a fragment activity:
`FacebookFragment.java` and
`fragmnet_facebook.xml`.

In `fragment_facebook.xml`, I added

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fb"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fa6a6a"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And in `FacebookFragment.java`

```
package com.appmaids.socialhub;
import com.appmaids.socialhub.R;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.webkit.WebView;
public class FacebookFragment extends Fragment {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facebook, container, false);
    final WebView myWebview = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    myWebview.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com");
    myWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    return rootView;
 }
}
```

I am getting an error as:
**The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type FacebookFragment**.
I don't know what to do, someone please help! I am using eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

### Correct

```
 View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_facebook, container, false);
 final WebView myWebview = (WebView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.webView1);
```